# How to display data with Ember.js, scope change?

Tags: ember.js

I'm having a heck of a time wrapping my mind around this. I've got my navigation bar and I want to imply add the clients name to the bar to show they are logged in for instance.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>{{Client.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{#linkTo 'clients'}}Favorites{{/linkTo}}</td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
</nav>
<!-- Main Body -->
 {{outlet}
</script>
```

So for instance, I've got a client who can log in and manage their ice cream flavor favorites. In the nav, how should I go about displaying the clients name? Just for reference, I've got a Fixture name App.Client with firstName and lastName as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `displayName` property in your corresponding controller. Then check if logged in inside of it and return the displayName.

```
displayName: function() {
  if (loggedIn) {
    return this.get('model').firstName
  } else {
    return ''
  }
}.property()
```

And change the corresponding template to use `{{displayName}}`. In general If there other issues try posting a [jsbin](http://www.jsbin.com) example along with a question.